ifcopenshell issue - gltf serializer
I upgraded ifcopenshel from v0.7 to v0.8, and serializing to gltf it gives me an error:
GltfSerializer.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settings'

this is my code:
settings = ifcopenshell.geom.settings(APPLY_DEFAULT_MATERIALS=True, WELD_VERTICES=False)
sr_2 = ifcopenshell.geom.serializers.gltf(f'{ff_name}.gltf',settings)

I downgraded back to v0.7 and works like before, but is it a version change on the serializers or is it a bug I should report??
